# How a circle $S^1$ acts on the Cayley plane $OP^2$ with exactly three fixed points?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory

The complex projective $CP^2$, the quaternionic projective space $HP^2$, and the octonionic projective space $OP^2$ each admit a circle action with $3$ fixed
points.

The circle action on $HP^2$ can be found in https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4731v2.

But how the circle acts on $OP^2$ with exactly $3$ fixed points?

Comment: According to the paper you cite, this is "known". My guess is to take a sufficiently generic circle inside the group Spin(9), in analogy with what they do in that paper.